# Letting :hover transition complete even when not hovering on element

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, pseudo-element

I've been building a photography website [here](http://www.europeanbob.co.uk/phil/index.html) but i'm having an issue with the :hover transitions in the gallery pages. It loads two links that lay over the thumbnails, one opens the image in fancybox and the other sets the image as the background.

Everything works fine, but if you hover off of the thumbnail before the transition is finished, it animates back to its original state.

Is there a way to let the transition play out before reverting to its idle state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming JavaScript isn't out of the question, [jQuery will certainly let you have this behaviour](http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/) using the .hover() method's ability to accept two callbacks, one for the hover, one for when the hover stops.

```
$("div.thumb").hover(function(){
    // show the magnifying glasses
    $(this).animate({ top: "0", opacity: 1 });
}, function() {
    // hide the magnifying glasses
    $(this).animate({ top: "-100px", opacity: 0 });
});
```